# Why the cpu usage of one process decreased when multiple processes are running?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'm using gnu parallel like below:

```
find conf/20230214/ -name "conf.yaml" | parallel run_backtest
```

the `run_backtest` is a function which will read the conf.yaml and run some code.

When there is only one conf.yaml in conf/20230214/, the cpu usage of this process could be 200%

```
PID    USER PR NI VIRT    RES   SHR  S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
154561 xxx  20 0 1355764  1.1g  3608 R  200  0.1  0:32.25  bt_atm
```

when there are 2/3/4 conf.yaml in conf/20230214/, the cpu usage of each process will descrease to 120%/100%/80%

Comment: Other subsystem bottleneck (RAM, IO, network, etc.). Your CPU is capable of running a single task but the system cannot run many of them.

Answer (score 0):

As AST writes this is typically due to bottlenecks in the system.

On my system it is almost always disk IO.

```
iostat -dkx 1
```

is excellent for seeing how loaded the disks are.

Too much parallelization can slow down the processing, so the optimal parallelization can really only be determined by trying out different amount of parallelization (https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/).